# what feature is missing in SQL Azure

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

SQL Azure seems pretty cool. Some things are not available in SQL Azure though. For example, you can't do switch database with a USE statement - which is pretty understandable.

What other features are missing in SQL Azure?

Comment: This is off-topic for SO.  Discussion questions should be on a forum, not a Q&A Site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SQL Server Feature Limitations (SQL Azure Database)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff394115.aspx)

[Guidelines and Limitations (SQL Azure Database)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff394102.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Here's a decent round-up of a feature comparison between SQL Azure and SQL Server.  It's a big list of items - probably too big to enumerate here.

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/compare-sql-server-with-sql-azure.aspx

Here's a [list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee336267.aspx) of partially supported T-SQL statements.
Here's a [list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee336253.aspx) of unsupported T-SQL statements.